# How to use formula on numbers extracted from a text data

Tags: excel-formula

An elementary example of my problem with an Excel workbook *(French version)*:

In A1: EUR 53,00

In A2 : EUR 12,50

In B1 the formula : `=DROITE(A1;NBCAR(A1)-4)` yields `53,00`

In B2 analogously : `=DROITE(A2;NBCAR(A2)-4)` yields `12,50`

Now, in B3, I use the formula: `=somme(B1:B2)` then it yields `0,00`

Similarly, if I use the formula: `=produit(B1:B2)` it also yields `0,00`

However : `= B1+B2` yields correctly `65,50`

Seems that formulas cannot compute, or they are interpreting the integers as strings (?). Of course, I've tried various ways to format cells so that they are integers, with no avail.
Any idea to solve this will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you perform your first operation it is a string operation.  You are pulling a string from a portion of a string.  In other words you're pulling a portion of text from a bigger piece of text.  While your text may look like numbers, they are still numbers stored as text.

When numbers as text and booleans TRUE and FALSE are sent through a math operation they are converted to number automatically by the system.  Unfortunately Sum (Somme) and Product (Produit) are both functions, not math operators.  Some functions may be set up to deal with numbers as strings, others are not.

To solve your situation you have a few options.  After taking your number as a string, you can send it through a math operation that will not affect its value such as *1, /1, +0 or you could use the VALUE function.  Try the following adjustments and see if they work for you:

```
DROITE(A1;NBCAR(A1)-4)*1

CNUM(DROITE(A1;NBCAR(A1)-4))
```

Comment: Thanks. Not seen your answer before placing my own answer. And you offer two different solutions instead of one…

Answer (score 0):

Discovered that one can use CNUM to tell the "text" is a "number".

Thus use in B1 : =CNUM(DROITE(A1;NBCAR(A1)-4)) and similarly in B2.

The functions now apply correctly to these numbers.

This is inconsistent since =B1+B2 was working : in that case B1 and B2 were correctly recognized as numbers. But at least the above repair works.

It is Microsoft, what can you expect…